# cross domain upload with uploadify

Tags: javascript, django, cross-domain, uploadify

I am trying to upload the video file to youtube youtube data api(using python client library)  through uploadify,

this is what i am trying

```
     $('#id_file').uploadify({
        'uploader'          : uploadify.swf',
        'script'            : 'https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload...........(youtube post url)',
        'scriptAccess'      : 'always',
    });
```

but i am getting flash security error while uploading

this is the screenshot of error msg.

[image],

does uploadify support third party upload? or do i need to do any configuration for that ?

any input will help.

thanks

Comment: Your question is to vague to get a useful answer. Where are you uploading to? S3? Your own server? That info would be helpful. What security error are you getting? Please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: while it might be possible to do that. I see so many security alarm bells going off, it's deafening

Comment: Hi @stevejalim, thanks for your suggestion, i edited the question see if you get what problem i am facing.

Comment: @Gaurav24 Try inspecting the response with your browser's developer tools (look for the failed request in the Network tab) and see if you get more data out of there.

Comment: @stevejalim, i cant see the actual post happening for the youtube url there, i see GET "https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml" which is returning 200, but after this instead of doing post it is redirecting to my site url. before that only i am getting security error.